# Removing duplicates from two comma separated strings

Tags: php, arrays

I'm comparing two comma-separated strings and completely removing duplicates. That is, if an item exists in both strings, it will not exist in the result.

For example, the result of comparing `cat,dog,alligator` and `alligator,parakeet` will be `cat,dog,parakeet`.

The solution I'm using involves converting the strings to arrays to compare.

```
$result = array_merge( array_diff($old, $new), array_diff($new, $old) );
```

The above works, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way (regular expressions, string comparisons) to do the comparison without converting the strings to arrays first. Or is the performance hit for the above solution really not that bad?

Thanks

Comment: How many elements at your arrays?

Comment: How do you convert the strings into arrays?

Comment: Re:TheHorse. At the moment the string will never have more than a handful of items. But, I am treating this as a thinking exercise, so I am curious how to handle something like this if there were a very large number of items.

Comment: RE:hakre. I'm using the PHP explode method.

Comment: Could you show an example of putting duplicates into another array?

Answer (score 2):

Array operations are definitely going to be efficient enough, unless you're trying to squeeze a few seconds out of a million-item calculation. Your solution is the simplest, and performs perfectly well, so is therefore the best.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. Optionally, there are regular expressions that could do the work. But arrays are much faster in this case. To minimize function calls you I'd write something like this:

```
$str1 = "cat,dog,alligator";
$str2 = "alligator,parakeet";

$result = array_unique((array) explode(',', $str1 . ',' . $str2));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The array_unique method can't be used in this context because it simply removes the "extras". I'm looking for the item to be removed completely >> "cat,dog,tree" + "dog,sidewalk" = "cat,tree,sidewalk" (notice how "dog" is removed completely).

Comment: This does meet the OPs specification. Furthermore, although regular expressions *could* do this, I highly doubt it is a more performant approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this as [Set Math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29). In your case you want the union minus the intersection (i.e. symmetric difference).

For example:

```
$result = array_diff(array_merge($s1, $s2), array_intersection($s1, $s2));
```

Although you could loop over each item and perform the logic yourself (Such as the answer from **TheHorse**), in the end, I believe PHP's native array functions are going to be more performant and offer more flexibility (e.g. multiple sets).

With that said, your solution works and is the PHP equivalent representation of the symmetric difference. So why change it...

Comment: Thanks Jason. You, jgendera and Chriszuma alluded to what I ultimately was wondering: If converting the strings to arrays first was faster than regular expressions or string comparisons.

Comment: It's possible for *small* strings that it might be faster. But as noted, the native PHP functions are more robust and likely more performant even so.

Answer (score 0):

For big number of element's good solution is:

```
<?php
  $temp = sort(array_merge($old, $new)); /* n*log(n); */
  $res = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($temp); $i++)
  {
     if ((count($res) == 0) || ($res[count($res) - 1] !== $temp[$i]))
       $res.append($temp[$i]);
  } 
?>
```

P.S. You can optimize that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the code does not entirely remove duplicates. It does ensure every item appears only once, but I'm looking for the duplicate to be completely removed from both strings.